# Measurement protocol offline hits not tied to website activity

Tags: session

Situation:
Customer buys a subscription plan and is being charged monthly. Customer only logged into the website once to buy the plan and we only have old session_id and timestamps. We have user_id and client_id saved. Every month we shoot event from the back end using measurement protocol for each plan extension (subscription).

Question:
Is it possible to send offline measurement protocol hits which are not tied to use'sr website activity? All events that involve active session_id are visible and being displayed in ga4 reports and debug_view but we cannot see any events that are not tied to active session_id, are we missing something in our setup or is measurement protocol limitation? Is there any work around?

We were expecting that server-side measurement protocol hits will be visible in our reports and we will be able to see offline events which are not tied to website activity.